# PHP Curl to test Sabre RESTful API Authentication Failing

Tags: php, rest, curl, sabre

I have managed to connect happily to Sabre's RESTful API and get my authentication token with my test key/secret. However, the next step I am struggling with - I am new-ish to curl so forgive my ignorance. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

$key is my Sabre-generated authentication token

```
$url = "https://api.test.sabre.com/v2/shop/flights/fares?origin=ATL&destination=LAS&departuredate=2016-06-30&lengthofstay=3,4,5,6,7&maxfare=250";
$header[] = "Authorization: Bearer " . $key;
$header[] = "Accept: application/json";
//should use http 1.1 by default
//uses GET by default

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump(json_decode($content));
```

I thought it might be the wrong URL. I don't have a production API key, just a test one. However changing the url to the production URL (removing test.) doesn't make a difference.

Here's the error from Sabre

```
object(stdClass)[2]
public 'status' => string 'NotProcessed' (length=12)
public 'type' => string 'Validation' (length=10)
public 'errorCode' => string 'ERR.2SG.SEC.MISSING_CREDENTIALS' (length=31)
public 'timeStamp' => string '2016-03-10T01:17:19.556-06:00' (length=29)
public 'message' => string 'Authentication data is missing' (length=30)`
```

Have I messed up my header somehow?

In step 4 of this: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_basics/authentication it says the header should be

> Authorization: Bearer {your token}

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot. I didn't destroy my previous $header var.